# Selecting all items in a ListBox Winform Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to select all items in ListBox and made this extension method for this purpose:

```
    public static void SetSelectedAllItems(this ListBox ctl)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ctl.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            ctl.SetSelected(i, true);
        }
    }
```

Problem is that if I have lots of items in the ListBox, it takes a long time to accomplish this task and I can watch how the ListBox is automatically scrolling down and selecting items.

Is there a way to temporary pause the update of a control, so that the task would finish faster? I tried using:

```
ctl.SuspendLayout();
  for (int i = 0; i < ctl.Items.Count; i++)
  ...
ctl.ResumeLayout();
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call the [`BeginUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.beginupdate.aspx) and [`EndUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.endupdate.aspx) methods to prevent the drawing/rendering of the control while properties on that control are being set.

Here is the revised code:

```
public static void SetSelectedAllItems(this ListBox ctl)
{
    ctl.BeginUpdate();

    for (int i = 0; i < ctl.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        ctl.SetSelected(i, true);
    }

    ctl.EndUpdate();
}
```

You said that you've tried calling [`SuspendLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx) and [`ResumeLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resumelayout.aspx), but that only affects the control's layout events. This pair of methods is used when you want to change a control's position relative to other controls, like when you set the `Size`, `Location`, `Anchor`, or `Dock` properties.