# Combobox "Select All" in linq query

Tags: winforms, linq, combobox

I have multiple comboboxes that pass a value to a linq query. Previously I was handling it with

```
    if(combobox.text == "select all")
       {combobox.text = "")
```

And then using the StartsWith(combobox.text) method to do the comparison, I know this is wrong. Since "jim" would return "Jimmy". How do I select all when "select all" is selected?

Comment: May help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934241/listbox-select-all-items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best would be to conditionally add the query filter:

```
var query = dataSource.foo.AsQueryable();
//you may or may not need AsQueryable() depending on what "foo" is
//if it is not queryable, you may need AsEnumerable(), or simply nothing

if (!combobox.Text.Equals("select all"))
    query = query.Where(x => x.Equals(combobox.Text));

return query.ToList();
```

---

The "simpler" way would be to use a boolean `or`, but the resulting query is uglier and may or may not be translatable to SQL (if that is what you are using):

```
var query = dataSource.foo
    .Where(x => combobox.Text.Equals("select all") || x.Equals(combobox.Text));
```

Comment: That's what I thought it was gonna come to, hoping there was a simpler way.

Comment: I've demonstrated the "simpler" way, using an or-expression, but it's probably not the better choice unless you know that the optimizer will remove the superfluous comparisons

Comment: Thought about it for a bit and came up with a lazy way that should work 99.9999% of the time StartsWith() && EndsWith()

Comment: @user2525463 Be careful if you're using Linq to SQL because EndsWith cannot use indexes.

Comment: @Ic Using Linq to xml