# How to select all items in a ListBox really fast?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have an ownerdrawn ListBox on a form (Windows Forms) binding to a datasource (BindingList).
I need to provide an option to select all items (up to 500000) really fast.

This is what I am currently doing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox.Items.Count; i++)
    listBox.SetSelected(i, true);
```

This is incredibly slow and not acceptable. Does anybody know a better solution?

Comment: Better making some effort to reduce that number of items instead.

Comment: Haven't used forms for a long time. Are you able to do something like `listBox.SelectedItems = listBox.Items`? And for `SelectedIndexes`?

Comment: @Steve: Nice try ;) No, that's no option.

Comment: Off-topic, but I don't see how a listbox containing 500,000 items would be usable. You may want to review your design.

Comment: @Rob: No, SelectedItems is get only.

Comment: Did you used BeginUpdate and EndUpdate before selecting the items?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I am not discussing the need of a listbox of that size.

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do after the selection of all those items?

Comment: [PInvoke](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13020429/43846) should be fastest

Comment: @MauriceStam Windows Forms

Comment: Using a DataGridView instead of a ListBox would make this a much faster operation.  Also, we don't put solutions in the question, let the answers take care of that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming this is a `Windows Forms` problem: Windows Forms will draw changes after each selected item. To disable drawing and enable it after you're done use the `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` methods.

```
listBox.BeginUpdate();

for (int i = 0; i < listBox.Items.Count; i++)
    listBox.SetSelected(i, true);

listBox.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: Perfect! This is a lot faster.

Comment: @Maertin See question

Comment: @Norman I've added the code in the example. Best not to duplicate solutions in a question. The voting system should put the best solutions at top. The community might still decide another solution would be better!

Comment: Reminder - be sure to check any events you tied to selection changes. That can slow this down, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a way that was fast enough to be acceptable.
I tried BeginUpdate/EndUpdate which helped but still took 4.3 seconds on a intel core i5 laptop.
So this is pretty lame but it works - at least it does in the IDE.
the ListBox is called lbxItems on the form I have a button called Select All. In that button's click event I have:

```
//save the current scroll position
int iTopIndex = lbxItems.TopIndex;

//select the [0] item (for my purposes this is the top item in the list)
lbxItems.SetSelected(0, true);

// put focus on the listbox
lbxItems.Focus();

//then send Shift/End (+ {END}) to SendKeys.SendWait
SendKeys.SendWait("+{END}");

// restore the view (scroll position)
lbxItems.TopIndex = iTopIndex;
```

result: This selects 10,000 items in a few milliseconds. The same as it would it I actually used the keyboard

Comment: Strangely if I put this in a KeyPress handler to respond to Ctrl-A it intermitently invokes sticky keys even though I have sticky keys disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can try listbox.SelectAll();

Following is link to microsoft documentation on ListBox SelectAll():

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectall(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That is for WPF, not Windows Forms.

Answer (score -1):

You can use SelectAll() method.

Listbox.SelectAll();

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectall(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: @MauriceStam's suggestion coupled with this may be the best solution (Not sure if `SelectAll` internally disables drawing or not)

Comment: It depends whether he is using WPF or Windows Forms. WF does not have the `SelectAll` method.

Comment: That's for WPF. The questioner is using Windows Forms (since WPF does not have `SetSelected()`).

Comment: Yeah, Windows Forms, sorry ;)

Comment: Oh okay sorry. You could do something like this to make it slightly quicker. a = Listbox.Items.Count; and loop using a.

Answer (score -1):

Found another way, that's "more faster":

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
internal static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

// Select All
SendMessage(listBox.Handle, 0x185, (IntPtr)1, (IntPtr)(-1));

// Unselect All
SendMessage(listBox.Handle, 0x185, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)(-1));
```

Comment: This doesn't update SelectedItems nor SelectedIndices.

Comment: @TonyEdgecombe As you can see from the question this isn't a requirement.